# Pycharm does not find module with one interpreter but does with another, why?

Tags: python, module, pycharm, package-managers

I am trying to install a package called "quantecon" through PyCharm. If I have Python 3.5 as an interpreter then I can find the package in the settings menu. But I need to run Anaconda, it has a bunch of other packages I need like scipy, numpy, etc. Once I install Anaconda and use it as the interpreter (it runs on Python 3.5 and a bunch of other packages) quantecon disappears from the menu of modules in PyCharm. Why does quantecon appear with one interpreter and not with another when they both run on python 3.5? This only happens with PyCharm. If I use jupyter/ipython notebook I can have both Anaconda and quantecon.

I prefer working with PyCharm, it would be ideal to be able to have both Anaconda and quantecon there. How can I install quantecon and have Anaconda as the interpreter?

Thanks

Comment: Because Anaconda uses a separate python binary and python path than your system one. In other words, you have two python interpreters: Anaconda (which has all the anaconda modules in the path), and your system one (which has all the system modules in the path). You just need to update your python path to tell one or the other where to find stuff.

Comment: @RPGillespie thank you for your message. How can I update the python path? Im new to this thing... Should I do that through PyCharm? If so, how?

Comment: Don't update the Python path, you should not mess with it unless you really have to, which is almost definitely not the case. You just need to change the interpreter PyCharm is using. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the interpreter in PyCharm?

If not, go to File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter and change the interpreter to the one in Anaconda. It should find the package, unless it's installed in a weird location.

If you don't have the Anaconda interpreter in the list of available interpreters, you can easily add it that dialog as well. Click the gear icon, select "Add local" and navigate to the `python` executable from Anaconda.

Comment: The problem is that he is trying to import conda modules from system python or vice versa. I don't think this will fix it.

Comment: I have actually tried this but quantecon does not appear in the options when the interpreter is Anaconda with Python 3.5

Comment: Then I would say you don't have quantecom installed in Anaconda. See if it is present in the list of installed packages: `conda list`. If not, you should be able to install it with `conta install quantecon`.

Answer (score 1):

In PyCharm 2019, I had to remove all interpreters, then re-add the one that should have worked all along.

Go to `File->Settings` (or `ctrl`+`Alt`+`S`),
Type `'interpreter'` in search
Select `'Project Interpreter'` on the left pane.
Press the `'Cog' icon` -> `Show All`
remove all interpreters using the `'-'` button as many times as needed.

Now add your interpreter.

That solved it for me.

Comment: I wonder how this is not an accepted answer. It worked for me thank you (though I had to restart the IDE after adding /usr/bin/python3.7 as interpreter)

Answer (score 0):

Inside PyCharm, in Ubuntu, go to `File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter` and change the interpreter. If Anaconda is not there, click on the gear, add local and then go to `/home/user/anaconda2/bin/python`

Comment: The problem is that he is trying to import conda modules from system python or vice versa. I don't think this will fix it.

Comment: I have actually tried this but quantecon does not appear on the menu

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to install quantecon to your anaconda:

https://anaconda.org/pypi/quantecon

(make sure you use anaconda's version of pip, not system pip)

You could also try to create a new Conda environment that has quantecon in it:

http://www.quantecon.org/wiki_py_conda_dev_env.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Sorry if I am too inexperienced on this, but how can I do that? I downloaded the tarball from the link you posted and tried to throw the file on pkgs folder.. that didnt work. I tried running the pip install command that is on the link you provided, that did not work either (I did this in the console at the bottom of the PyCharm interface).

Comment: What operating system are you using?